# Get the latest row inserted with the help of CreatedDate field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to get the latest record inserted in a SQL table based on its CreatedDate. For instance, in the table below, I would like to get the third row.

```
A   B   C   2009-05-04 19:30:52.847
A   B   D   2009-05-04 19:30:55.050
A   B   E   2009-05-04 19:30:57.003
```

I have a working query, but I am wondering if there is better way to achieve the same result. Below is the table, data and query I am using right now for my test. Is there any better way to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (
  ColumnA     NVARCHAR(10),
  ColumnB     NVARCHAR(10),
  ColumnC     NVARCHAR(10),
  CreatedDate DATETIME    DEFAULT Getutcdate())

INSERT INTO TestTable(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C');
INSERT INTO TestTable(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'D');
INSERT INTO TestTable(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'E');

SELECT *
FROM   TestTable
WHERE  CreatedDate = (SELECT   Max(CreatedDate)
                      FROM     TestTable
                      WHERE    ColumnA = 'A'
                               AND ColumnB = 'B'
                      GROUP BY ColumnA,
                               ColumnB)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also write

```
SELECT top 1 *
FROM   TestTable
order by CreatedDate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I like that outer join solution - it hadn't occured to me.  But *Display Estimated Execution Plan* found it to be more expensive than the way I usually solve this problem.  (Could be related to the indexes on my table - your mileage may vary) Give this one a try:

```
SELECT
    T1.ColumnA,
    T1.ColumnB,
    T1.ColumnC,
    T1.CreatedDate
FROM
    dbo.TestTable T1
    JOIN (SELECT ColumnA,
                 ColumnB,
                 max(CreatedDate) MaxDate
          FROM
                 dbo.TestTable
          GROUP BY ColumnA,
                   ColumnB) T2
    ON  T1.ColumnA     = T2.ColumnA
    AND T1.ColumnB     = T2.ColumnB
    AND T1.CreatedDate = T2.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to skin this cat. Some that haven't been posted yet:

```
SELECT
     T1.column_a,
     T1.column_b,
     T1.column_c,
     T1.created_date
FROM
     dbo.Test_Table T1
WHERE
     T1.column_a = 'A' AND
     T1.column_b = 'B' AND
     NOT EXISTS
     (
          SELECT
               *
          FROM
               dbo.Test_Table T2
          WHERE
               T2.column_a = T1.column_a AND
               T2.column_b = T1.column_b AND
               T2.created_date > T1.created_date
     )
```

or

```
SELECT
     T1.column_a,
     T1.column_b,
     T1.column_c,
     T1.created_date
FROM
     dbo.Test_Table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Test_Table T2 ON
     T2.column_a = T1.column_a AND
     T2.column_b = T1.column_b AND
     T2.created_date > T1.created_date
WHERE
     T1.column_a = 'A' AND
     T1.column_b = 'B' AND
     T2.column_a IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM TestTable
WHERE ColumnA = 'A'
  AND ColumnB = 'B'
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

This is just in case there are duplicates by `CreatedDate` and you need all of them.

Otherwise just drop `WITH TIES`.